# Daylight Hours Calculation

Tags: math, trigonometry, julian-date

I am having problem to get a numerical value for this expression where I am trying to calculate the daylight hours using this formula. Its ending up giving a NaN when I evaluate
this expression.

> J stand for Julian day. (for e.g today J = 172;)

Any help will be highly valuable,
Thanks

```
P = Math.asin(0.39795*Math.cos(0.2163108 + 2*Math.atan(0.9671396*Math.tan[0.00860*(J-186)])));
```

Comment: In these situations, when I have problems, I always devide the code into multiple lines, to avoid confusions like your case. Try it and you'll see where the "error" is coming from.

Comment: @NunoGonçalves..i did, its coming from this part "*Math.tan[0.00860*(J-186)]"

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with J ... Make sure it return a good value...

Comment: @NunoGonçalves..when i remove the part, *Math.tan[0.00860*(J-186)], it works perfectly. Thats why im so surprised why its not working.

Comment: @LolCat...I tried as you said and I even replaced it with a number, yet same error. I tried using firebug to debug the problem, but no error is detected.

Comment: I tried it ... and it says : Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group' on Math.tan[0.00860*(J-186)] ... I removed the [ to ( and it worked ...

Comment: I tried using wolfram to see if I was writing the formula incorrectly, but it worked perfectly over there.

Comment: @LolCat..Thanks dude, it works now! Cheers.. I just replaced the square brackets with parentheses and it worked.

Comment: @Elkun nice! I wrote an answer for other users, accept it so they can see the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and got an answer ... :

```
P = Math.Asin(0.39795 * Math.Cos(0.2163108 + 2 * Math.Atan(0.9671396 * Math.Tan(0.00860 * (J- 186)))));
```

I changed the **"["** to **"("** in Math.tan[0.00860*(J-186)])))

And I got a result ... (To test it I changed J to 172)

Make sure the P is a **Double**

Answer (score 0):

```
    //GET LATITUDE
            latitude = document.getElementById("latit").value;
            L = latitude;

            //GET JULIAN DAY
              Now=new Date();
              Now_Y=Now.getYear();
              if (Now_Y < 70)   { Now_Y=Now_Y*1+2000; }
              if (Now_Y < 1900) { Now_Y=Now_Y*1+1900; }
              Now_M=Now.getMonth();                     // Jan-Dec = 0-11
              Now_D=Now.getDate();                      // 1-31
              Now_H=Now.getHours();                     // 0-23
              Now_N=Now.getMinutes();                   // 0-59
              Now_S=Now.getSeconds();                   // 0-59
              Now_U=Now.getMilliseconds();              // 0-999
              Now_T=Now.getTime();                      // miliseconds since 1970-01-01
              Now_O=Now.getTimezoneOffset();            // in minutes
              Now_W=Now.getDay();                       // weekday: Sun-Sat = 0-6
              Now_J=                                    // day of year (Julian day)
                Math.round((                            // ...account for DST
                (new Date(Now_Y,Now_M,Now_D))           // ...most recent midnight
                - (new Date(Now_Y,0,0)))                // ...Dec. 31st midnight
                /86400000);                             // ...mili-seconds per day
              Gmt_N=Now_N+Now_O;
              Gmt=new Date(Now_Y,Now_M,Now_D,Now_H,Gmt_N,Now_S);
              Gmt_Y=Gmt.getYear();
              if (Gmt_Y < 70)   { Gmt_Y=Gmt_Y*1+2000; }
              if (Gmt_Y < 1900) { Gmt_Y=Gmt_Y*1+1900; }
              Gmt_M=Gmt.getMonth();                     // Jan-Dec = 0-11
              Gmt_D=Gmt.getDate();                      // 1-31
              Gmt_J=                                    // day of year (Julian day)
                Math.round((                            // ...account for DST
                (new Date(Gmt_Y,Gmt_M,Gmt_D))           // ...most recent midnight
                - (new Date(Gmt_Y,0,0)))                // ...Dec. 31st midnight
                /86400000);                             // ...mili-seconds per day
                alert("Julian Day: "+Gmt_J);

            J = Gmt_J;

            P = Math.asin(0.39795*Math.cos(0.2163108 + 2*Math.atan(0.9671396*Math.tan(0.00860*(J-186)))));

            alert("P is : "+P)

            pi = 3.14159265;

            var D = 24 - (24/pi)*Math.acos((Math.sin(0.8333*pi/180) + Math.sin(L*pi/180)*Math.sin(P))/ (Math.cos(L*pi/18

0)*Math.cos(P)));
```